# How can I convert multiple columns in a pandas dataframe into a column containing dictionaries of those columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe containing the following columns:

```
RegAddress.CareOf,RegAddress.POBox,RegAddress.AddressLine1,RegAddress.AddressLine2,RegAddress.PostTown,RegAddress.County,RegAddress.Country,RegAddress.PostCode
```

I am inserting this dataframe (loaded from a CSV) into a relational database, and so would like to convert these columns into a single column, `RegAddress`, containing a dictionary, which contains the keys `CareOf, POBox, AddressLine1...` and so on. I cannot figure out how to do this in a vectorised fashion, i.e. go from:

```
RegAddress.CareOf,RegAddress.POBox
Me,2
You,3
```

to:

```
RegAddress
{"CareOf": "Me", "POBox": 2}
{"CareOf": "You", "POBox": 3}
```

efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.apply()` method to achieve this:

```py
selected_cols = ['RegAddress.CareOf', 'RegAddress.POBox']

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['RegAddress'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: {
        col.split('.')[1]: row[col] for col in row.index
        if col in selected_cols
    },
    axis=1
)
```

Result:

```
                      RegAddress
0   {'CareOf': 'Me', 'POBox': 2}
1  {'CareOf': 'You', 'POBox': 3}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also have a lot of columns - how can I cleanly specify which I want to apply this lambda to?

Comment: @DomWhite You can use a list to specify the columns to which you want to apply the lambda function. I edited the answer.